# How to put a comma on top of a greek letter?

Tags: greek

```
\documentclass[a4paper,onesided,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fbe_tez}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\roman{enumi})}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Graphics will be here
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[dvips]{color}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx, epsfig}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,color}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{textalpha}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\makephdtitle % M.S. thesis
\makeapprovalpage
\newpage
\null
\vspace{\fill}
\begin{flushright}
τὸ μὲν σῶμά ἐστιν ἡμῖν σῆμα\\
Plato
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

I editted my question with my actual code, I need to write the phrase "τὸ μὲν σῶμά ἐστιν ἡμῖν σῆμα" to the first page of a purely mathematical thesis. I tried the things below, kind comments, still no output.

I need left and right facing actual commas, and over a greek letter.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I.e., rough and smooth breathing marks

Comment: I do not get what is the problem sorry

Comment: Please provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/9077).

Comment: oh I will sorry

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[greek.polytonic]{babel}

\begin{document}

ἐστιν ἡμῖν

\end{document}
```

---

You provided no example, but in comments suggest the document is not all Greek, so:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[greek.polytonic,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

some english \textgreek{ἐστιν ἡμῖν}  Plato

\end{document}
```

Comment: `ἐ`  is actually `\accpsili\textepsilon` if you need a "latex accent command markup"

Comment: thank you very much for your help, but I could not manage to obtain it. my notes are below

\begin{flushright}
"$\tau \grave{\omicron}$ $\mu \grave{\varepsilon}$$\nu$ $\sigma \tilde{\omega} \mu \acute{\alpha}$ ἐστιν ἡμῖν $\sigma \tilde{\eta} \mu \alpha$"\\
Plato
\end{flushright}

Comment: don't use math for textual Greek.  @semaseymen did you try exactly what I wrote above in the answer?

Comment: @semaseymen see updated answer

Comment: I tried the updated version, thank you, but still no output:(

Comment: \begin{flushright}
"$\tau \grave{\omicron}$ $\mu \grave{\varepsilon}$$\nu$ $\sigma \tilde{\omega} \mu \acute{\alpha}$ \textgreek{ἐστιν ἡμῖν} $\sigma \tilde{\eta} \mu \alpha$"\\
Plato
\end{flushright}

Comment: @semaseymen No! Try what I posted, that is a complete document that makes the output shown. Fragments posted  in comments can not be debugged, and as I say you should have no math here.

Comment: when I write your comment solely, it works indeed, thank you. But I have tons of other commands and packages etc. above in my original work.

Comment: @semaseymenmake a small but _complete_ document that shows an error and ask about that in a new question. No one help if you just say you have an unshown error mssage from some unshown code.

Comment: @semaseymen but you need to stop using math mode and math accents such as `\acute` for text.

Comment: okay, this was my first post on this help page actually, I do not now how to use it properly. But you helped a lot, thank you so much for your effort.

Comment: The babel package option for ancient Greek, such as here, should be `greek.polutonic`.  You can also try `\usepackage[polytonicgreek, english, provide=*]{babel}`, according to the manual.

Comment: @Davislor ah yes, I'll update

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to David Carlisle’s great answer, you can do this without `babel` and with or without entering Unicode directly.  You should **not** be using math mode for Greek text.

But, first, unless your publisher is forcing you to use 8-bit legacy fonts in 2022, I would recommend that you switch to Unicode in LuaLaTeX ot XeLaTeX.  I’ve posted [several](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512245/61644) [examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579813/61644).  In 2022, one thing you might want to add to them is `\usepackage{inputnormalization}`, to work around certain bugs with hyphenation and combining accents that might not have been fixed.

In PDFTeX, a MWE would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % You have been able to leave this out since 2018.
\usepackage{textalpha}
\usepackage{parskip} % Just tweaking the formatting of this MWE.

\begin{document}

In precomposed Unicode, τὸ μὲνσῶμά ἐστιν ἡμῖν σῆμα.

With ASCII input, \texttau\accvaria{\textomicron}
\textmu\accvaria{\textepsilon}\textnu
\textsigma\accperispomeni{\textomega}\textmu\acctonos{\textalpha}
\accpsili{\textepsilon}\textsigma\texttau\textiota\textnu{}
\accdasia{\textnu}\textmu\accperispomeni{\textiota}\textnu{}
\textsigma\accperispomeni{\texteta}\textmu\textalpha.

\end{document}
```

[image: Computer Modern sample]

What this does not get you and `babel` does is hyphenation.

The text-mode commands you need are defined for the LGR encoding, and if all you need are a few unhyphenated words, `\usepackage{textalpha}` lets you just type them in without an additional command to set the language or 8-bit font encoding.

If you use Unicode input in PDFTeX, it **must** be precomposed characters from the Greek Extended block, in NFC form.  Legacy 8-bit tools do not understand Unicode combining accents.

In the LGR encoding, the commands for breathing accents you’re looking for are `\accdasia` and `\accpsili`.  You can look up the full set in `lgrenc.def`.  Here, I used the Greek names for accents, but `\'`, `` \` `` and `\~` would also work, instead of `\acctonos`, `accvaria` and `\accperispomeni`.

Some gotchas to look out for: commands such as `\textnu \accpsili` will gobble spaces unless you add an extra pair of braces as I do in the MWE, and you must use `\textautosigma` or `\textfinalsigma` to get ς rather than σ at the end of words.

Comment: Oof. Some typoes in there.

Comment: thank you so much for this great effort. I editted my question.

Answer (score 2):

If you're at stake with inputting Greek letters (and are using `pdflatex`) you can use the standard transliteration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\foreignlanguage{greek}{t`o m`en s~wm'a >estin <hm~in s~hma}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the circumflex cannot go above omicron and epsilon, so I changed them into omega and eta. This reflects the quotation from [Plato's Gorgias we find on Perseus](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0177%3Atext%3DGorg.%3Asection%3D493a)

[image]

Here's the tables for transliteration and for inputting diacritics and punctuation (from `texdoc cbfonts`).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, I tried but no out put. I do not get what is wrong with my code. I editted my question with my code

Comment: @semaseymen You didn’t load babel as shown nor use the proper command